# jpa bulk insert not inserting properly

Tags: jsf, jpa, persistence, bulkinsert

i am developing jsf with jpa project now i am in problem with bulk insert for about list size is more than 6000 that means it should insert more than 6000 records in the table but it inserts only 215 records.

my code is here

```
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            try {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                for (int i = 0; i < sgmlList.size(); i++) {
                    // Getting the object from the list by using loop
                    SGML sgml = sgmlList.get(i);
                    em.persist(sgml);

                }
em.getTransaction().commit();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage("SGML imported successfully"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            } finally {
                if (em != null) {
                    em.close();
                }
            }
```

and my persistence xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Cation" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.cation.bean.Users</class>
        <class>com.cation.bean.BatchInfo</class>
        <class>com.cation.bean.SGML</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.4:3306/cation"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="rix"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="rix123"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

i've tried this code also when it persist the object in the list

```
if (i % 200 == 0) {
                    em.flush();
                    em.clear();
                }
```

but then also same issue arises. Can anyone help to solve this issue plz.

Comment: can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?  You are handling all errors and ignoring them, remove this to catch the error.